# What time format is this?

Tags: time-format

I'm going through this list of dates and times and I've been googling for a few days now and haven't figured out this time format:

```
201612102200038814 -> 10.12.2016 19:01
201611182200029224 -> 18.11.2016 11:55 
201611162200028449 -> 16.11.2016 19:06
2016080521998919 -> 5.8.2016 19:47
2016091522320593 -> 15.9.2016 18:53
```

It's obvious that the first 8 digits (20161210) are YYYYMMDD, but latter part doesn't make any sense to me....

Do you have any ideas? Is it even a valid time format?

Comment: It would help if you could obtain more than a *single* sample - we could construct an infinite number of possible translations that all include the one data point you've currently supplied.

Comment: ...I added some more examples. :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be some kind of timestamp, since 2,200,029,224 is very close to 2,200,028,449, and the dates of each are only 2 days apart. So the difference is 775, and the date difference is roughly 1.75 days.

The difference between the first two is 9590, which is larger, which makes sense since the difference between those dates is almost a month.

The oldest date you have in the list also has the smallest timestamp, which is consistent with this theory.

The ratios also match up. 775 / 1.75 days = 442. 9590 / 22 days = 435. If I calculated exact seconds differences I bet these ratios would match up nearly perfectly. So then each hour the timestamp goes up by 18 (roughly), or 3 every 10 minutes. This is a pretty bizarre timestamp, but it does fit, and can be used to calculate dates from the given timestamp.